# Optional argument to an environment inside align

Tags: environments, align, matrices, optional-arguments

I have lots of matrices so I want to define a `mat` environment.  I sometimes need the matrix to have right-aligned columns so I am using `mathtools` and I want to have an optional argument that is usually `c` but that I can make `r` when I want.

A small working example is below.  The definition works great in lots of cases, including inside the `equation*` but inside of `align*` it fails.
Specifically, I get `! Extra }, or forgotten $. <recently read> } l.22 \end{align*}`.

If I add `[c]` or `[r]` as optional arguments to the `mat` inside the `align*` then compilation will succeed.  Adding a `\` (slash, space) to the first line of the `mat`, before the `&\vdots`, also works.

To me this looks like a problem with LaTeX trying to read the optional argument when I don't want it to.  I've tried putting `%`'s in various places in the `\begin{pmatrix*}[#1]` line but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\newenvironment{mat}[1][c]{\begin{pmatrix*}[#1]
      }{\end{pmatrix*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{mat}
           &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
           &\vdots
  \end{mat}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{mat}
           &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
           &\vdots
  \end{mat}
  &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an expansion time problem. A way out comes from `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mat}{O{c}}
  {\begin{pmatrix*}[#1]}
  {\end{pmatrix*}}
```

### Solution without `xparse`

Redefine `\env@matrix`, but not with `\renewcommand`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix{\new@ifnextchar[\env@m@trix{\env@m@trix[c]}}
\def\env@m@trix[#1]{%
 \hskip-\arraycolsep\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols#1}}
\makeatother
```

This will allow you to use an optional argument to the `Xmatrix` environments; however you can't define an abbreviation with `\newenvironment`. This will work (with or without the optional argument)

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}[r]
           &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
           &\vdots
  \end{pmatrix}
  &= 0
\end{align*}
```

If you want an abbreviation, then the magic formula

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\mat\csname pmatrix*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endmat\csname endpmatrix*\endcsname
```

will allow you to write

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{mat}
           &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
           &\vdots
  \end{mat}
\end{align}
```

with or without the optional argument.

## Solution with minimal impact

(Thanks to Bruno Le Floch)

Write

```
\begin{mat}
\relax & \vdots                    \\
\cdots & ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
       & \vdots
\end{mat}
```

Comment: Thank you but that gives me an internal LaTeX3 error: Module kernel, message name "command-already-defined":
Arguments '\if_num:w' and '\ifnum'.  (However, my LaTeX3 is old since I use what comes stock with Ubuntu, so I think it is TeXLive 2009.)

Comment: @JimHefferon I'll try and investigate more on a "pure LaTeX" solution that avoids braces around the environment. Upgrading to TeX Live 2011 is not so difficult.

Comment: @JimHefferon A (not so nice) solution is on line

Comment: @egreg The reason Jim's code fails is that LaTeX skips spaces when looking for the optional argument: then TeX sees `&` when looking for the optional arg, and the dreaded `\halign` cell-building mechanism is triggered. Three solutions: not skip spaces, as when you use `xparse`; surround the environment with braces, as in Herbert's answer (this effectively hides `&` from TeX); or do some hack similar to what AMSmath's own environment do with <code>\ifnum`{=0\fi\iffalse}\fi</code>. Also, your last mat* should be mat.

Comment: Thank you to Bruno and egreg.  (As I mentioned to Herbert, I have hundreds of instances of mat and I was hoping to avoid special-casing those that appear inside an align, or similar bad spot.  But perhaps I cannot.)

Answer (score 5):

put the `mat` environment into braces:

```
\begin{align*}
 { \begin{mat}
           &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
           &\vdots
  \end{mat} }
  &= 0
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thank you, Herbert.  I have hundreds of instances of mat (it is a book) and I was hoping to avoid special-casing such as putting in the slash-space, or your solution.  But perhaps I need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a new command for easy matrix typing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pma}[2][r]{\begin{pmatrix*}[#1] #2 \end{pmatrix*} } %pmatrix shortcut

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \pma{
    &\vdots                    \\
    \cdots &ra_{j,i}+sb_{j,i} &\cdots \\
    &\vdots
    }
    &= 0
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And I have no problems with align